# Is it necessary to use then in Axios response?

Tags: typescript, axios

I have started using Axios recently for API testing along with typescript and nodejs. Recently, I got a review comment from one of the reviewers that we need to use async, await while doing axios api calls as we are using ES6.

Can someone give me an example of such a scenario? My current code looks like this.

```
public listAllID's = async (idType: string, idOption: string) => {

    let ids:[
      {
        id: string [];
      }
    ];
    await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://test-abc.com/api/v1/Allids',
      data: {
        "type": idType,
        "include": idOption
      },
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tokenId,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      json: true
    }).then((response: { data: any; status: any }) => {
      ids = response.data;
      console.log(ids);
      let statusCode = response.status;
      console.log(statusCode);
      expect(statusCode).to.be.equal(200);
    });
  }
}
```

In this scenario, I am getting all id's which I need to send to some other method which on the basis of these ids, will create a new request (post) with each id.

This is called by this method:

```
Then(
  /^I list all ids of "([^"]*)" with other option  as "([^"]*)" from API$/, async (idType: string, idOption: string) => {
    await element.listAllIdsFromAPI(idType, idOption);
  });
```

I come from java background and newbie in typescript, node, and Axios. Any help/suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: If you're using `await` you can get rid of `then`, just `const response = await axios({... ` Have a look at async functions [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Can you modify the above code in your answer? I am confused about the parameter () part.